# call curl between particular period of time within day

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

I have to execute a URL using curl and if the output contains a "hello" string, then I will exit successfully out of the shell script otherwise I keep retrying till 8 AM in the morning and then exit with an error message if it still doesn't contain that string.

I got below script but I am not able to understand how I can run while loop till 8 AM and if still curl output doesn't contain "hello" string?

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    curl -s -m 2  "some_url" 2>&1 | grep "hello"
    sleep 15m
done
```

So if it is after 3 PM then start making curl call until 8 AM and if it is successful with that curl call giving "hello" string, exit successfully otherwise after 8AM exit with error message.

And if it is before 3 PM  then it will keep sleeping until it is passed 3 PM.

I have to add this logic within script and I can't use cron here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the script as follows, tested with `GNU date`

```
#/bin/bash

retCode=0                                      # Initializing return code to of the piped commands
while [[ "$(date +"%T")" < '08:00:00' ]];      # loop from current time to next occurence of '08:00:00'
do
    curl -s -m 2  "some_url" 2>&1 | grep "hello" 
    retCode=$?                                 # Storing the return code
    [[ $retCode ]] && break                    # breaking the loop and exiting on success           
    sleep 15m                                  
done

[[ $retCode -eq 1 ]] && echo "String not found" >> /dev/stderr  # If the search string is not found till the last minute, print the error message
```

Comment: In this case, it will keep looping in while loop until it is 8AM right? Can we exit asap as soon as it is successful. And if it is not successful, then keep trying till 8AM and then exit with non zero status code and with error message?

Comment: @user1950349: Refer my update, changes done to exit on success and error message is already printed on failure, refer  the last line.

Comment: one basic thing, instead of using `break` in while loop if I use `exit 0` then it will be same thing? And also in the last line if I have to exit with non zero status code like `exit 2` along with print an error message, then how will we do that?

Comment: Do `[[ $retCode -eq 1 ]] && echo "String not found" >> /dev/stderr && exit 2`. And don't use exit inside the loop, it by default returns error code `0`, since it has run without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `date +%k` to retrieve current hour and compare with 8 AM and 13 PM. Code may like this

```
hour=`date +%k`
echo $hour
if [[ $hour -gt 15 || $hour -lt 8 ]]; then
    echo 'in ranage'
else
    echo 'out of range'
fi
```